# How to get my API to return more than one value in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input

My CLI project is working almost correctly, however, is only returning one value. I would like my program to return multiple values.

Here's the code:

```
def display_info 
  puts "You'll love the following spots!"
  puts "********************************"
  @objects.each.with_index(1) {|brewery, index| puts "#{index}. #{brewery.name}"}  
  puts  "Please make a selection by index number for more information:"
  puts  "****************************************************"
  puts  "Type Quit to end. Type Menu to try another location."
  input = gets.strip.downcase
  if(input.to_i > 0)
    @brewery = @objects[input.to_i - 1] 
    puts "name: #{@brewery.name}"
    puts "street: #{@brewery.street}"
    puts "city: #{@brewery.city}"
    puts "phone: #{@brewery.phone}"
    puts "website_url: #{@brewery.website_url}"
    display_info
  elsif (input == "quit")
    quit 
  elsif (input == "menu")
    start
  else 
    puts "Ooops, please try again to get more info:"
    display_info
  end 
end
```

Here's the input result if that helps.

```
    Austin
You'll love the following spots!
********************************
1. Oasis Texas Brewing Company
Please make a selection by index number for more information:
****************************************************
Type Quit to end. Type Menu to try another location.
quit
Goodbye. Drink responsibly and enjoy.
```

What can I do to return more than one value?

Here's the source of this code. This is the content.

```
    class Breweries::API

  def self.get_breweries(input)
    @breweries_hash = HTTParty.get("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=#{input}")
    return if @breweries_hash.empty? #empty array handle 
    breweries_obj = {
      name: @breweries_hash[1]["name"],
      street: @breweries_hash[3]["street"],
      city: @breweries_hash[4]["city"],
      phone: @breweries_hash[10]["phone"],
      website_url: @breweries_hash[11]["website_url"]
    }
    Breweries::HoppyCode.new(breweries_obj)
  end
end 

end
```

Comment: Can you add more details to the question? By multiple values what do you mean? If you want to return some value multiple times maybe ```yield``` can work for you

Comment: It's _highly_ recommended to use proper indentation when writing code. While Ruby doesn't insist on it, it helps you when debugging and helps others understand your code. Any decent editor will understand Ruby and indent and outdent as necessary. Also whitespace between lines is important when writing logical blocks. "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live. Code for readability." — John Woods

Comment: I added the rest of the info. Thanks for your answers and suggestions so far.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the string you capture using `gets` with a character. You should ask for it in your message, normally that would be a comma, possibly surrounded by spaces.

I extracted the problem in a simplified script so that you can test it separately, which is always a good idea when solving a problem.

Mind the use of regular expressions between the `//` delimiters, and followed by the `i` flag to indicate that the comparison should be case-insensitive.

```
# what you would receive when you type this in the console following your message
# and captured by the gets, in this case brewerie 1 and 3
input = "1, 3" 
#split by a comma preceded or followed or not by a space
breweries = input.split(/ *, */) 
breweries.each do |brewerie|
  if(brewerie.to_i > 0)
    # @brewery = @objects[input.to_i - 1] 
    puts "displaying info about #{brewerie}"
  elsif brewerie[/quit/i]
    # quit
  elsif brewerie[/menu/i]
    # start
  else 
    puts "Ooops, please try again to get more info:"
    # display_info
  end 
end
```

Which returns:

```
displaying info about 1
displaying info about 3
```

Comment: I'm new to this and maybe I still don't have much understanding. But I'm still not getting the output I want.
Let's say I enter any city, for example: Chicago.
I want the list like this:
1. Brewery #1
2. Brewery #2 
3. Brewery #3
For some reason, I still don't understand how to get more than one brewery. Any other suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question code isn't runnable at this moment, eg the contents of your @objects is missing, we would have to guess, so please first complete your question
take an example at my anwer, you just need to paste and you can run the code and it only contains the minimum for testing the problem at hand
Also, do you input the string "Chicago" ? or a number ?

Comment: I added the rest of the info. Thanks for your answers and suggestions so far.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, You are asking the user to pick a brewery from a list of breweries. When they pick one, you show its info to them. What you could do instead is display a list of cities and let them pick a city and select all elements of the `@objects` where the city matches

```
def display_info 
  arr_of_cities = []
  @objects.each{|element| arr_of_cities.push(element.city)}
  arr_of_cities.each.with_index(1) {|city, index| puts "#{index}.#{city}"}  
  puts  "Please make a selection by index number for more information:"
  puts  "****************************************************"
  puts  "Type Quit to end. Type Menu to try another location."
  input = gets.strip.downcase
  arr_of_breweries = @objects.where(city:arr_of_cities[input.to_i- 1])
  if(input.to_i > 0)
    arr_of_breweries.each.with_index(1) do |brewery,index|
    puts "#{index}"
    puts "name: #{@brewery.name}"
    puts "street: #{@brewery.street}"
    puts "city: #{@brewery.city}"
    puts "phone: #{@brewery.phone}"
    puts "website_url: #{@brewery.website_url}"
   end
    display_info
  elsif (input == "quit")
    quit 
  elsif (input == "menu")
    start
  else 
    puts "Ooops, please try again to get more info:"
    display_info
  end 
end
```

Hopefully that helps. I haven't used ruby in a while so my syntax might be off a bit.

Comment: I added the rest of the info. Thanks for your answers and suggestions so far.